# NSBatchUpdateRequest not making updates

Tags: core-data, nsbatchupdaterequest

I'm trying to do a batch update and I'm not getting an exception, but it's telling me 0 records are updated.  If I run the following code

```swift
let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Order")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sql_ident IN %@", completed)
request.propertiesToUpdate = ["complete" : true]
request.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType

do {                
    let res = try moc.executeRequest(request) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
    print("Set \(res.result!) objects to complete (should be \(completed.count))")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}                   

let r = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Order")
r.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sql_ident IN %@", completed)
let count = moc.countForFetchRequest(r, error: nil)
print("I found \(count) orders")
```

Then I get this output:
    Set 0 objects to complete (should be 6470)
    I found 6470 orders

So it's definitely seeing the objects I expect it to, but it's not updating any of them.   What am I doing wrong here?

If it makes any difference, this is in a child context

Comment: These objects didn't start out as `"complete" : true`, correct?

Comment: That's correct, they all default to false.